# SSRS: calculation with input

Tags: reporting-services

I am new in SSRS and I would like to know if it is possible in SSRS to create blank fields in which you can enter values and this values should calculated with a value in the implemented query. Something like this here.
[image]

And if this is possible how can I do something like this? With Parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only input the user can make to a report is via [parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In the report itself you cannot use SSRS to create input fields. The only way to input data would be to use parameters in the toolbar and pass through the data through that way, with your output appearing in the rendered report

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of parameters inside a report. For example, you can use a date if you want the data of a certain day. In your case you'll need an int box and enter the value in there.

[image]